# Html agenda data: table or "div"?

Tags: html, tabular

I'm trying to build an html weekly agenda (just for fun).
At first I didn't use tables to do it.

But I found an exemple where tables are used for sudoku (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-table-element.html#the-table-element).

So I was wondering: Is table the best semantic approach for a weekly agenda? With events that might be on multiple days?

Comment: Is this going to be an email? If so TABLES all the time

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Tables should be used for tabular data.

Answer (score -1):

I think using div and in general css box model would be better becouse in an agenda you don't need just a tabular presentation but a more complex structure to rapresent, for example, events that are scheduled on multiple hours or multiple days. Tables should be used when you have a **fixed** structure as sudoku has.

Comment: Tables can represent events on multiple hours or multiple days. But my question is not about layout presentation but semantic meaning of the tags i'm gonna use